# How to pass a bool value from called function back to the calling function

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I was pretty sure I had the basics down, but maybe not, as I can't seem to understand why my `bar()` function won't receive the updated `bool` value from `foo()`. Would someone be able to help me understand where I'm going wrong here?

I'm sure it's probably something silly, but after digging around on the net and looking at some examples, I can't seem to get it quite right.

**Expected Behaviour**

`bar()` should output `console.log('true');`

**Current Behaviour**

`bar()` currently outputs `console.log('false');`

Thanks in advance.

```js
class test {

  constructor() {
    this.bar();
  }

  foo(bool) {
    bool = true;
    return bool; // Return bool with 'true' value
  }

  bar() {
    let bool = false
    this.foo(bool);
    console.log(bool); // Console the updated value.
  }

}
new test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the return value. Change your `bar` function:

```js
bar() {
    let bool = false
    bool = this.foo(bool);
    console.log(bool); // Console the updated value.
}
```

Comment: Fml, . Noted, thanks for the assist. 

Comment: @Beaniie Even the greatest of minds sometimes make the tiniest of mistakes